# How to get checked value from mat-checkbox in angular jasmine test?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-material, jasmine

I would like to write test if checkbox is checked when item.done is true.
When i try to get checked value from mat-checkbox in jasmine test, it always is undefined. What do I wrong?

I have material checkbox defined as: (and it works fine)

```
<mat-checkbox id=checkbox [checked]="item.done" (change)="toggle(item)"  color="primary">...</mat-checkbox>
```

and my test defined as:

```
it( 'checkbox should be checked when done is true', fakeAsync(() => {
   component.item.done = true
   fixture.detectChanges()
   const checkbox = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('mat-checkbox')
   console.log(checkbox.checked)
   expect(checkbox.checked).toBeTruthy()
}));
```

console.log(checkbox) returns:

```
<mat-checkbox _ngcontent-a-c116="" id="checkbox" color="primary" class="mat-checkbox mat-primary" ng-reflect-id="checkbox" ng-reflect-color="primary" ng-reflect-checked="true">...</mat-checkbox>
```